# How to add repository for tomcat maven plugin

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, plugins, maven

How do I include the repository for the tomcat maven plugin found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/source-repository.html))? I can't find version 2.0 in the central maven repository so I am guessing I have to include it myself. I am not getting luck doing that in my pom.xml file. Any ideas if this is the wrong syntax?

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-tomcat</id>
        <url>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/maven-plugin/trunk/tomcat-maven-plugin</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

This is the warning that I get when I execute the tomcat:run goal:

> The POM for
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT is
>   missing, no dependency information available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this plugin is in the maven central repository, so you only need to configure it in your pom (if you need to overwrite the plugin's default configuration values).

That svn address doesn't fit there, it's the address where source code for this plugin is, not the binaries. Maven expects the address of a Maven Plugin repository there. The binaries are in the default repository and Maven will download any needed dependencies automatically when invoking one of its goals. For instance `mvn tomcat:deploy`

[Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html) you can find how to configure it in your `pom.xml`.

And [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) you can find its goals and how to use it.

Comment: if I search the central repository for "tomcat-maven-plugin", I don't see any version 2.0... The latest there is 1.1!

Comment: Version 2.0 seems to be under development, as stated [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html). You could always get the source code from that SVN and compile it for your use, but being it in development phase, it'll probably be somewhat unstable. Sorry, the links I gave are for the 2.0 version. These are 1.1: [goals](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) and [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I'll try it out. I am running tomcat v7.0 so as long as version 1.1 is compatible with tomcat v7, it'll be good..