# Warning when create maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

When I create a simply maven web project in my package explorer, I have a little icon with a warning but i haven't warning in "Error Log" (the project name is **testM2**)

I followed this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeC7XQho-O0

Here the picture:

[image: the warning say]
.

what is the problem? I just create new project, have you an idea?

Comment: take a look in the "Markers" view. this may help

Comment: It would be nice to have no false warnings/errors in Eclipse/Maven projects, but I've never found that to be an attainable goal.

Comment: @PhilippSander in "Markers" I have it: Description Resource Path Location Type
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.  testM3  Build path JRE System Library Problem

Comment: there you have it ;-)

Comment: Maybe you need to add the maven compiler plugin to your `pom.xml` specifying a more modern JRE? (1.6 or 1.7)

Comment: @ericwilson ok i have to specify new maven compiler, but I need to use tomcat maven plugin...

Comment: I funded this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404790/how-to-add-repository-for-tomcat-maven-plugin but the answer's links are not found can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In my case same warning has come.  [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs3I4.png)

There was warning appeared in the project folder. So the build path problem.  Go to Project --->  properties. Check any misconfiguration there. In my case, incompatible between jdk and jre. So I replaced it as soon as the warning disappears.

Please check your built path configuration